# create multi step form in Drupal 7

Tags: forms, drupal-7, drupal-modules, multi-step

Which way is best to  create multi step form in Drupal 7,

I have used Mform,Multistep node form,

Please give me some Best modules refrence. which module is best to create multistep form

Comment: Please refer [create-multi-step-form-drupal-7](http://jamesdavidson.io/blog/how-create-multi-step-form-drupal-7) . It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create yours with the Drupal Form API Reference https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7 and with this structure

```
$form['step1']['element1']
$form['step1']['element2']
$form['step2']['element1']
$form['step2']['element2']
```

...

and by displaying only the step1, step2 and all of your steps with this method.